# Save ping results to TXT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to build a script that will save some ping result info to a text file. The only info I really need is date, time, ipaddress, % of loss, and average time.
I have been able to make parts of this work.

I can get the time and date to save to the text file but nothing else. 
The other problem I'm having is when I do get it to save to a text file it saved 100s of results to the file. I only want it to save the final result. Then when I rerun the file it would add a new entry to the text file.

Here is a sample of what I have been playing with:

```
@echo on
SET ip=10.22.222.54
@echo. %date% at %time% to %ip%>>PingLogs.txt
ping %ip% -n 1 >>Logs.txt
stop
```

This is what I expect it to look like when saving to a text file:

> 06/07/2019 : 21:54 : 10.22.222.54 - 0% - 0ms,
>   06/07/2019 : 20:18 : 10.22.222.54 - 0% - 0ms,

Comment: How do you expect to have a line which looks like the example you've provided when you're making no attempt at doing so. What you're telling it to do is to output a line which looks line this: `06/07/2019 at 21:54:39.20 to 10.22.222.54`, _(with a leading space character)_, into a file named `PingLogs.txt`. Then you're outputting probably `6`-`8` lines from the `ping` command to another file named `Logs.txt`. We're not here to write your code for you, you have to make some effort, and as it stands you have not made enough, please try a little harder!

Comment: @Compo thank you for the 411 but as you can see i have started to try and figure this out. echo. %date% at %time% to %ip%>>PingLogs.txt saves some data to the txt file how ever its on going (Quote 100s of records added) even though in the next line it is set to 1. now back to my question and to make it as simple as potable for you how do i save % loss and ms to the txt file and only have it save one record when its set to 1.

Comment: If you cannot understand that you're outputting to two different text files and when you send `at` and `to` to the first one, it cannot magically change that to `:` and `:` you should stop scripting. Additionally, I've read your question and it does not ask `how do i save % loss and ms to the txt file and only have it save one record when its set to 1`. Whilst @Stephan may have been good enough to read between the lines with your poorly constructed question, you need to consider that non english speaking readers also need to understand your question. Currently it is simply not good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for /f` loop to catch the output of a command. As your command `ping` output several lines, it needs a lot of analyzing to find out the correct tokens and delimiters to get the desired parts. Then just reassemble them to your needs and put a loop around:

```
@echo off
set "IP=www.google.de"
:loop
set "loss="
for /f "tokens=1,9 delims=( " %%a in ('ping -n 1 %IP% ^|findstr "%% ms,"') do (
    if not defined loss (set "loss=%%a") else (set "average=%%b")
)
echo %date% : %time% : %IP% - %loss% - %average%
goto :loop
```

(Note: `findstr "%% ms,"` looks for lines that contain a `%` (has to be escaped with another `%`) and/or the string `ms,` - exactly the two lines, we need). You could also use `findstr "loss Average", but then the script would only work on English Windows versions. I like to keep my scripts as language independent as possible.

Output:

```
07.06.2019 : 19:40:39,37 : www.google.com - 0% - 13ms
07.06.2019 : 19:40:41,25 : www.google.com - 0% - 13ms
07.06.2019 : 19:40:43,24 : www.google.com - 0% - 15ms
07.06.2019 : 19:40:45,25 : www.google.com - 0% - 13ms
07.06.2019 : 19:40:47,24 : www.google.com - 0% - 13ms
```

Note: date/time format depends on locale settings - yours probably look different.

Note: with `ping -n 1` don't expect loss to be anything other than either `0%` or `100%`

Note: with `ping -n 1`, `Minimum`, `Maximum` and `Average` all are the same (this script takes `Average` nevertheless, so if you use something other than `/n 1`, the output is still what you expect)

Comment: I get this error 
C:\Users\kelly\Desktop\bat file>set "IP=www.google.com"

C:\Users\kelly\Desktop\bat file>set "loss="

C:\Users\kelly\Desktop\bat file>for /F "tokens=1,9 delims=( " %a in ('ping -n 1 www.google.com |findstr "% ms,"') do (if not defined loss (set "loss=%a" )  else (set "average=%b" ) )

Comment: that's no error, that's command repetition. You obviously forgot the `@echo off`

Comment: Its there but just found out i have to run it as an Administrator for it to work for some reason. to save it to a text file i added >>Logs.txt to the line echo %date% : %time% : %IP% - %loss% - %average% but this does not work am i missing something?

Comment: I got it i added `echo. %date% : %time% : %IP% - %loss% - %average% > C:\Users\kelly\Desktop\log.txt` on the next line after echo %date% : %time% : %IP% - %loss% - %average%

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to ensure that the date and time format were always presented in the same way, you could use this .bat file script to call a PowerShell script. Put both of these scripts in the same directory.

=== pip.bat

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dp0pip.ps1" >pip.txt
```

=== pip.ps1

```
$Computers = @('localhost', 'asdfa')
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    if ($tc = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        ForEach-Object {
            "{0} : {1} : {2} - {3}% - {4}" -f @(
                (Get-Date -f "MM/dd/yyyy")
                , (Get-Date -f "HH:mm")
                , $tc.Address
                , "0"
                , $tc.ResponseTime
            )
        }
    } else {
        "{0} : {1} : {2} - {3}% - {4}" -f @(
            (Get-Date -f "MM/dd/yyyy")
            , (Get-Date -f "HH:mm")
            , $Computer
            , "100"
            , 0
        )
    }
}
```